# Is it possible to polymorph 2 characters into a Tarrasque using True Polymorph?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, polymorph

Is it possible to use *true polymorph* to transform 2 PC characters, each of whom is at least level 15, into a CR 30 Tarrasque?

Comment: Do not answer in comments.

Answer (score 14):

### No, this will not work

*True Polymorph* has no inherent ability to combine creatures as it is written and cannot be presumed to do so.

The closest I could get to seeing this being possible is having a Sorcerer cast *True Polymorph* from a scroll or other source and use the *twinned spell* metamagic. This effect applied to your situation would polymorph your two level 15 PCs into two of the same monster but they would still be separate monsters of CR 15 or lower. Twinned spell applies the effects of the spell to two targets but does not change the spell's text.

A similar question addressed an issue like this here: [Can I make independent spell-effect choices for a Twinned spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64379/48893)