# When do I have to declare that I want to twin my spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, metamagic

When do I have to declare that I want to use the Twinned Spell Metamagic on my spell: before the attack roll, after the attack roll or after the DM tells me if it hits or not?

Also do I lose the sorcery points if I have to declare it before the attack roll and it misses?

Comment: Related: [How many attack/damage rolls does a sorcerer make when using the Twinned Spell metamagic option?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48935/33707)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Before the attack roll is made

From [Metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/Sorcerer#Metamagic) section, Twinned Spell (PHB, p. 102):

> ***When* you cast a spell** that targets only one creature and doesn't have a range of self, **you *can* spend a number of sorcery points** equal to the spell's level to **target a second creature in range with the *same spell*** (1 sorcery point if the spell is a cantrip).

"When" you cast the spell means that you must declare that you want to use the Twinned Spell Metamagic *before* the attack roll has been resolved.

This makes sense considering that you are targeting a second creature with the same casting of that spell. If you declared the use of Twinned Spell any later than before the attack roll, then it would be as though you are gaining a second attack, a second casting of the same spell.

Unfortunately, this does mean that, if your attack misses, the sorcery points are wasted.

Comment: Also, you make a separate attack roll for each target, right? So even if you could decide after, it wouldn't give you any extra information about whether the sorcery point(s) would be wasted?

Comment: @Kazim It might. If there are two of the same creature, you could target one and see what happens. If you rolled high and it missed, you'd know that its AC is too high for you to hit, so you could choose to not Twin the spell because it would probably miss. The rule is written to prevent this.

Comment: @anaximander good point, didn't think of that!