# At what point in the casting of a spell would twinning the spell still be possible?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, sorcerer, metamagic

This came up when a sorcerer cast chromatic orb in my campaign. It was only after hitting and rolling damage that the sorcerer decided he wanted to twin the chromatic orb, and I ruled that he should have declared he was twinning the spell when he cast the spell, and not after knowing the results.

He was frustrated when he read the description of twinned spell and didn't see that explicitly stated.

At what point in casting a spell would twinning the spell still be possible?

Comment: Related: "[When must the wizard choose to overchannel?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/66917)"

Comment: I have closed your question as a duplicate as I believe it has effectively been asked before. Know that this isn't a bad thing, and actually helps people find the older question. If you feel [the marked question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142079) does *not* answer yours, simply explain why in a comment or an [edit] to the question; your question can always be reopened. That all said, welcome to RPG.SE, please take the [tour] if you haven't already done so and feel free to add a comment or visit the [help] for further guidance. Best of luck and happy gaming!