# Does the Death Domain cleric's Touch of Death Channel Divinity option affect both targets of a spell from the Improved Reaper feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, damage, cleric, targeting

At 17th level, the [Death Domain cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#DeathDomain)'s Improved Reaper feature (DMG p. 96-97) lets them target two creatures (within 5 feet of each other) instead of one with necromancy spells, given they are within 5 feet of one another.

If I cast Inflict Wounds using Improved Reaper on two targets next to each other, can one use of the Touch of Death Channel Divinity option deal extra damage to both?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Touch of Death affects only one creature

The [Channel Divinity: Touch of Death](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#ChannelDivinity:TouchofDeath-597) feature states (DMG, p. 97; emphasis mine):

> Starting at 2nd level, the cleric can use Channel Divinity to destroy **another creature's** life force by touch.
>
> When the cleric hits **a creature** with a melee attack, the cleric can use Channel Divinity to deal extra necrotic damage to **the target**. The damage equals 5 + twice his or her cleric level.

Note that this feature consistently uses the singular; it targets only a single creature. This feature can be used when you hit a creature, so if you wanted it to apply to both creatures you would have to use two uses of Channel Divinity.

Something to keep in mind is how Improved Reaper works, it is quite similar to the Sorcerer's Twinned Spell Metamagic which is discussed in the following Q/A:

- [How many attack/damage rolls does a sorcerer make when using the Twinned Spell metamagic option?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48935)

To summarize the answers there: when using this feature, if your spell involves an attack roll, you will make separate attack and damage rolls for each target.

Comment: A better question would be with "Sweeping Attack" which as written hits TWO creatures with ONE melee attack: "When you hit a creature with a melee weapon attack, you can expend one superiority die to attempt to damage another creature with the same attack. Choose another creature within 5 feet of the original target and within your reach. If the original attack roll would hit the second creature, it takes damage equal to the number you roll on your superiority die. The damage is of the same type dealt by the original attack."